# Como fazer um Loop funcionar dentro de outro Loop no mesmo código

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando listar duas categorias cadastradas no BD na tabela "CATEGORIA", conforme imagem abaixo:

Tabela Categoria

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas sempre que habilito a pagina **"pag_apresentacao.php"** onde listo os produtos, a lista de categoria limita-se a apenas a categoria "Portas Pivotantes", ignorando a outra com o nome "Tampos", e me trazendo todos os produtos cadastrados na Tabela "PRODUTOS" conforme imagem a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já quando desabilito a pagina **"pag_apresentacao.php"**, as duas categorias ficam a mostra, porém não é listado nenhum dos produtos cadastrados na tabela produtos, quando selecionado qualquer uma das categorias.

Solicito aos amigos, uma dica de como fazer com que eu possa listar as duas categorias, e trazer apenas os produtos referentes a categoria selecionada.

Abaixo estou postando os códigos que estou usando:

Listando as Categorias:

```
<!-- Listando os Categorias -->
<?php
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<div style="float:left; width:112px; height:133px; padding:2px 10px;" id="cats-list">
    <a class="cat-link" href="javascript:;" title="<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>">
        <img style="position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);" src="img_cate/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" width="100" title="<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>" />
    </a>
    <div style="background:#2f2140; margin-left:-300px; width:880px;z-index:999;border-radius:25px;" class="single-cat">
        <h1 align="center" style="width:830px; margin-top:-40px;"><?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?></h1>
        <div style="margin-left:357px;width:50px;" class="cat-links">
            <a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;" title="Voltar">
                <img src="img/fechar.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
<!-- Listando os Produtos por Categoria -->
<?php include "pag_lista_produtos.php"; ?>                  
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Listando os Produtos Por Categoria Selecionada: "pag_lista_produtos.php"

```
<!-- Listando os produtos -->
<?php
include "conexao.php";
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<div style="float:left; width:112px; height:133px; padding:2px 10px;" id="songs-list">
    <a class="song-link" href="javascript:;" title="">
        <img style="position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);" src="img_prod/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" width="100" title="<?php echo $res['titulo']; ?>" />
    </a>
    <div style=" margin-top:120px;z-index:999;border-bottom-right-radius:25px;border-top-right-radius:25px;" class="single-song">
        <div style="width:50px;margin-left:300px;" class="song-links">
            <a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;" title="Voltar">
                <img src="img/fechar.jpg" />
            </a>
            <div class="song-sides">
                <img style="margin:40px 0 0 -142px;" src="img_prod/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" width="369" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1> <?php echo $res['titulo']; ?> </h1>
        <div class="entry" style="overflow-y: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 100px; background:#fff;">
            <p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#ccc;">
            <?php echo nl2br($res['descricao']); ?>
            </p>
            <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 100px; height: auto;">
            <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100px;">
            </div></div></div>
            <span class="song-sides left-side"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Ficarei muito agradecido se os amigos puderem me ajudar a solucionar esses problemas.

Comment: Você está utilizando a função "fetch_array" e pegando o campo pelo nome da chave... Tente usar pegar pelo número da coluna $res[0] ou veja se dá certo trocando por "fetch_assoc"

Comment: Uma dica: Você criou a tabela de categorias mas está guardando o nome delas na tabela de produtos. O correto é guardar o código da categoria na tabela de produtos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, voce ta fazendo um loop dentro de outro loop e nomeando a variavel como no loop de fora. O que acontece é que as variaveis $query, $codigo e $imagem substitui o loop das categorias. Tenta renomear as variaveis do segundo loop como $query_produto, $codigo_produto, etc.

Comment: Bom dia @Samuel Pacheco, eu segui sua dica e deu certo, agora consigo trazer e visualizar as duas categorias cadastradas no BD. Abusando um pouco mais, teria como você me explicar como posso direcionar aos produtos referente a categoria selecionada, pois por enquanto sempre que seleciono qualquer uma das duas, o resultado é sempre o mesmo, trazendo todos os produtos cadastrados na tabela **"PRODUTOS"**. Tentei fazer o **href** assim ![HREF](http://www.lccinformatica.com.br/img/href.jpg), com um **Get** assim ![GET](http://www.lccinformatica.com.br/img/get.jpg), mas sem sucesso

Comment: O endereço para verificar como esta no momento é: (http://www.lccinformatica.com.br/). Se o amigo puder me dar mais essa ajuda, de como direcionar as categorias aos seus referentes produtos, ficarei grato.
E desde já meus agradecimentos pela atenção dispensada ao meu problema.

Comment: Eu nao consigo entender o seu codigo porque está muito bagunçado. Como vc esta começando a aprender, sugiro tentar com alguma coisa mais simples, como somente a listagem de categorias e produtos, depois tenta implementar o design e os scripts js.

Comment: Valeu @Samuel Pacheco, BRIGADÃO.